# How to use `onclick` inside javascript string literal

Tags: javascript, module, onclick, string-literals

**Is it possible to use `onclick` inside of a string literal?**

I have a `page` view like so:

```
const page = () => {
  const htmlOutput = `
    <button
      onclick="openMessageComposer"
      id="messageCta">Message</button> // Using the id works
  `;
  document.getElementById('app').innerHTML += htmlOutput;
  document.getElementById('messageCta').onclick = () => {
    console.log("openMessageComposer")
  }
}

export default page;
```

It's being used in a router like so:

```
import page from './page.js';

window.onload = () => {
  page()
}
```

which is imported in my `index.html` file as a module as `<script type="module" src="router.js"></script>`

This works.

However, I'd like to avoid `document.getElementById('messageCta').onclick`.  Is there a way to use the `onclick` event instead?

Something like

```
const openMessageComposer = () => {
  console.log("openMessageComposer")
}
```

which would exist inside the `page` component.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have two onclicks: one, in the inline attribute, which tries to reference a global variable named `openMessageComposer` but then does nothing with it. (your other is your `.onclick`) If you want to remove the `.onclick`, then just make sure the inline handler *invokes* the `openMessageComposer` function instead:

```
onclick="openMessageComposer()"
```

But inline attributes are generally considered to be pretty poor practice, and can make scripts significantly more difficult to manage, especially in larger codebases - I'd prefer your current method of assigning to the `onclick` *property* of the element.

If it's the requirement of adding the `id` to the appended element that you don't like, then create the element explicitly with `createElement` instead, so you have a direct reference to it, without giving it an `id`, and assign to its `onclick` property:

```
const page = () => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'Message';
  button.onclick = openMessageComposer;
  document.getElementById('app').appendChild(button);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!  Using `onclick="openMessageComposer()"` didn't seem to work either when I was experimenting, unfortunately.  I was aware of creating the button tag explicitly, but I think that's unnecessary since referencing the `id` works just fine.  I was trying to implement a more functional method (like React) of assigning the `onclick` event to a method.  Using the `onclick` property of the element the way I have it seems to be the only way that works.